# Why do we keep return types of interface methods for views and presenters void?

Tags: android

Why do we keep return types of interface methods for views and presenters void? I like the practice of doing this, but is there a technical/design principle that dictates this behavior?

An example for a todo app is here:

```
interface View extends BaseView<Presenter> {

    void setLoadingIndicator(boolean active);

    void showTasks(List<Task> tasks);

    void showAddTask();

    void showTaskDetailsUi(String taskId);

    void showTaskMarkedComplete();

    void showTaskMarkedActive();

    void showCompletedTasksCleared();

    void showLoadingTasksError();

    void showNoTasks();

    void showActiveFilterLabel();

    void showCompletedFilterLabel();

    void showAllFilterLabel();

    void showNoActiveTasks();

    void showNoCompletedTasks();

    void showSuccessfullySavedMessage();

    boolean isActive();

    void showFilteringPopUpMenu();
}
```

Comment: Google "command-query separation".

Comment: I will - Thank you for the direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather it is to follow the nature of the term interface.

An interface defines a contract for a behavior.

For example:

```
interface swimmer {
    void startSwim()
}
```

Animals that implement the swimmer interface can swim, but we don't want to tie that behavior to calculating and outputting the current speed or something like isSwimming().

So we mark the interface as returning void and can implement another method that allows us to retrieve the currentSpeed or isSwimming flag.

THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART:

There is a term for this and it is called command-query separation:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation

It states that methods should either perform an action or respond to a query, but not both.